# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined - Google MAP API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the autocomplete Google MAP API working. However, whenever I load the page I get an error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined'

HTML

```
<label>Location</label>
<input id="location_field" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Location">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
let locationField = document.getElementById('location_field');
let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(locationField);
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
     let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
     specifiedLocationObject = place;
});
```

I always get the error on this lin :

```
let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(locationField);
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing your code to the working [google example in the documentation](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are including a reference to the Google Maps JS script. If that is correct, if I had to guess, I would say that your JavaScript is probably running before the Google Maps script is finished processing.

A workaround for this is to include a callback function in the Google Maps script URL that can be called when the script is finished loading. You can then wrap the code you wish to execute in that callback function.

Example:

```
<script>
function initMap() {
    // your JS code, e.g....
    let locationField = document.getElementById('location_field');
    let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(locationField);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        specifiedLocationObject = place;
    });
}
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other root cause for this of course is that you *did* forgot to import the Google Maps JS script in your code. If you're using angular the directions are [here](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/google-maps#loading-the-api) but are generally similar across platform. Directions copied for posterity:

- First follow [these steps](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started) to get an API key that can be used to load Google Maps.
- Load the [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API).
- The Google Maps JavaScript API must be loaded before the GoogleMap component.